# PHP print script error

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement the script below to print the images on the supposed pages but it rather causes a problem to the pages instead.

```
 <?php
     if ($currentpage == '/services/') {
         print("<img src="path/to/services.png" alt=""/>");
     },
      if ($currentpage == 'contact.php') {
         print("<img src="path/to/image.png" alt=""/>")
     },
     else {
         print("<img src="path/to/image.png" alt=""/>")
     }
     ?>
```

The error message is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/master/public_html/wp-content/themes/siteripe-001/othe-rpages.php on line 173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need brackets if there is only one line of code in a block.
In your case, it is more efficient to use one `if` block with `elseif` and `else`, rather than several `if` blocks: you are always testing the same variable ($currentpage), so only ONE block will be executed.
I also replaced some double-quotes with single-quotes.

```
<?php
    if ($currentpage == '/services/')
        print('<img src="path/to/services.png" alt=""/>');
    elseif ($currentpage == 'contact.php')
        print('<img src="path/to/image.png" alt=""/>');
    else
        print('<img src="path/to/image.png" alt=""/>');
?>
```

Shouldn't the second image be `contact.png` instead of `image.png`?

Comment: Used it as you suggested but it still doesn't print the image, it shows it as a dead link.

Comment: Check the image path and filename.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed semicolon at the end of the last two print statements.
And also needs to escape the double quotes. You can use a backslash character before a doube quote to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some semi-colons and you had too many double-quotes. You need to nest the quotes, like below:

```
<?php
     if ($currentpage == '/services/') {
         print('<img src="path/to/services.png" alt=""/>');
     },
      if ($currentpage == 'contact.php') {
         print('<img src="path/to/image.png" alt=""/>');
     },
     else {
         print('<img src="path/to/image.png" alt=""/>');
     }
?>
```